# Bootstrap tab-pane data-toggle switch with button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Pills</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="pill" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#menu1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
    2. Next
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

(Overwrited from w3schools.)
I need as a result:
clicking on the **Next** (a href), and change the data-toggle part of the menu (ex. from home to menu1 as it given), but in the design, it doesn't shows as it was clicked onto menu1 (the menu1 doesn't appear as active menu). I already tried the for attribute, but no result. 
Any idea? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your next button always links to Menu1, and also never selects it

here is your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/hkawgm4d/3/

replace this:

```
<a href="#menu1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
```

with this:

```
<a id="btnNext" aria-expanded="false">
```

and include this javascript:

```
$('#btnNext').click(function(){
  $('.nav-pills > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```